# MS Dynamics: retrieve the schema of entities to use it in SOAP?

Tags: soap, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

I'm trying to add some entities via a SOAP client, to MS Dynamics (online). My client is not a Microsoft client.

Do you know a way to retrieve the schema of Entities like Account, Prospect etc... I would like to know how . I really need to know it , for integration with different installations of Dynamics.
I'd like to know the fields and when to put a String a Boolean etc.

I use a Demo instance of MS CRM online, from scratch, I did not change anything

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

You can get metadata about an entity or just one attribute on an entity by using a request. Here is a link to an example

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg594428.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to retrieve this information programmatically then follow Kevin Ross's answer above.

If you want to browse this information you can use the SDK Metadata Browser solution.

The Dynamics CRM Metadata Browser is in the SDK (SDK\Tools\MetadataBrowser). You can download the SDK from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40321.

Follow the README.DOCX that is in the **SDK\Tools\MetadaraBrowser** and you'll be able to see all the information necessary for manually building your SOAP calls.

Here is what it looks like:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Nick!The point is I'm not on windows and can't use the SDK, can't i?