# CRM: How to find the Value for OptionSetValue?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, crm, xrm

I am totally new to `CRM`. I am doing a code review.

The code is comparing value of `Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OptionSetValue.Value` with `100000002`.

I believe, `100000002` represents whether the Sales Order is completed (or some other state for Sales Order). I want to know from where can I find the values for `Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OptionSetValue.Value`?

I mean to ask from where can I get valid set of values for `Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OptionSetValue.Value`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamics CRM - Accessing Custom Product Option Value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16279214/dynamics-crm-accessing-custom-product-option-value)

Comment: just a note: 100000002 is clearly a custom state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this one helpful too (for searching manually):

http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ddcc3b05-b5a2-49a1-9555-152ad6134604/crm-reporting-where-are-attribute-picklist-values-stored?forum=crmdevelopment

(Refer answer by DavidJennaway.)

---

I searched for `StringMap` in my system and got the file in the workspace which contained all the values.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it programatically you can follow this answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/23354017/394978

If you want to do it visually you can follow this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22106272/394978

Answer (score 1):

There are two basic ways, through the SDK call, or creating early bound types.

See this answer [Dynamics CRM - Accessing Custom Product Option Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16279214/dynamics-crm-accessing-custom-product-option-value) for accessing it through the SDK Call.

For actually creating early bound types, use this: https://xrmearlyboundgenerator.codeplex.com/